# method.invoke of java reflection not picking correct method at runtime

Tags: java, reflection

```
String str="123/false"
String[] ss = str.split("/"); 
Object[] value = new Object[ss.length];
int ii=0;
for(Object s:ss){
  value[ii] = new Object();
  value[ii]=s;
  ii++;
}
```

`method.invoke(new Instance(), value)//` Invoke method is not identifying method at run time.

The method to be invoked is: `String getList(int i, Boolean f)`

It gets identified only if I use the following code:

```
method.invoke(new Instance(), new Integer(123), new Boolean(false))
```

Comment: What is the problem ? and how does it relate to the code you posted ?

Comment: value array holds [123, false] populated from the code given above. At run time method.invoke is not considering getList(int,Boolean).

Comment: Please consider editing your question and adding relevant part of your code to explain your problem. From the way it stands now, I don't anything will even hazard a guess as to what you're trying to ask.

Comment: If I get it right, you need the array `value` to contain `int` and `boolean` but you set there an `Object` and a `String`. Due to that Java cannot find method `String getList(Object,String)`

Comment: How did you get `method`? That is where the method gets chosen, not when you invoke it.

Comment: In java Reflection we have method.invoke(Object, Object args[]), after debugging my code I see method is correctly picked but still control is not going to the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need the array `value` to contain `int` and `Boolean` but you set there an `Object` at first which is replaced by a `String` after that. Due to that Java cannot invoke the method `String getList(int,Boolean)`, because `String` is not castable to `int` nor to `Boolean`. To fix that, you have to do something like this:

```
String str="123/false"
String[] ss = str.split("/"); 
Object[] value = new Object[ss.length];

// Conversion String to int, first parameter
value[0] = Integer.parseInt(ss[0]);  
// Conversion String to boolean, second parameter
value[1] = Boolean.parseBoolean(ss[1]); 

method.invoke(new Instance(), value);
```

Comment: For me 123 and false both are Strings, How can we say that 123 is integer and false is Boolean?

Comment: You have input as a `String`, that is clear, right? The split doesn't change it at all. All basic types like `Integer` and `Boolean` has static method starting with `parse` to convert `String` to given type if the `String` is correct. Otherwise it throws a ParseException or something like that.

Comment: You are correct Gaim but I did not wanted to write a method to impose Data types on the variables after splitting through string. Wanted invoke to set object values directly to the chosen method.

Comment: @gjosh That is not possible in Java. You can use array of parameters like `Object[]` but the given values has to match order and type based on Barbara Liskov principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle